# Accessing instance variables in an eventhandler with smalltalk

Tags: event-handling, smalltalk, squeak

I'm pretty new to smalltalk and an apparently easy problem drives me crazy.
My own class inheritates from the Morphic class and overwrites keyStroke

```
keyStroke: anEvent
Transcript show: myDigitClass.
(((anEvent keyValue) > 47) and: ((anEvent keyValue) < 58)) ifTrue: [
    "myDigitClass dropADigit"
    "myDigitClass setADigit: (anEvent keyValue) asCharacter."
    Transcript show: (anEvent keyValue) asCharacter
    ]
```

that works so far and the Transcript shows me my input I made on the keyboard *but* the instance variable myDigitClass is NIL even though I initialised this variable and passed it through a setter-method to this class. If access myDigitClass by a getter-method I wrote it works.

I call the showPane method and assign the input param digitMD to the instance Var.

```
showPane: digitMD
  |pane|
  myDigitClass := digitMD.

  pane := DigitMorph new.
  pane extent: 340@340.
  ^pane openInWorld.
```

And in the Workspace I do the following:

```
 myDigitClass := DigitClass new.
 myTest := DigitMorph new.
 myTest showPane: myDigitClass.
```

Comment: What dialect are you working with? Pharo, Squeak, VW, VA...?

Comment: After reading your last comment, I would like to see the code where you initialize the variable and also the code you used to declare the class (where the instance variable is defined).

Comment: Ok, I appended it in my question posting.

Comment: I tried to recreate your setup but I need to know the hierarchies: from which classes do `DigitClass` and `DigitMorph` inherit? Any other methods I need to get your example going? If you can, give me a file out of all the involved classes, that would be the easiest way I guess.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I finally solved the problem, in my "Show" method that draws the window I instantiate my overwritten Morph again so the references were wrong. I don't know what the devil has gotten into me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access instance variables directly by sending the object `#instVarNamed:`. This is a private method though and should only be used if you know what you are doing, or for debugging.

You would use `#instVarNamed:` in your example the following way, assuming the instance variable of your class is called `theDigit`:

```
...
Transcript show: (myDigitClass instVarNamed: 'theDigit').
...
```

The transcript will show the value effectively stored (e.g. `nil`).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sry i don't get it.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my answer to include more detail. Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite vague...
How do you know that the instance variable is NIL (`nil`?) ?
Is it what you get in the Transript?

Note that `Transcript show:` idiom is generally used with a String argument.
Otherwise, it send asString to the argument (at least in Squeak).

What does `yourMorph yourDigitGetter asString` would answer?

Comment: The point is that i want to call the dropADigit/setADigit method that i commented out in the snippet above. But if i do so i get a "MessageNotUnderstood" error. So i tried to show me the instance variable in the transcript and i get a nil but if a call the following method: `getDigitMD
^(myDigitClass).` and save the result in the workspace and show me this, it prints out "a DigitClass".

Comment: You mean when you use the "print it" menu? That will call a different method, #printString, not necessarily same as #asString. When you have a MessageNotUnderstood, the best thing is to open the Debugger, from there you can inspect all the states of the Object.